# Tener varios perfiles con Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

voy a intentar explicarme lo mejor posible por que es un poco lioso lo que quiero hacer,

por ejemplo yo programo Angular y React y cada Framework utiliza pues distintos Plugins en Visual Studio Code me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de crear tipo perfiles que por ejemplo yo pueda ir cambiando de uno a otro dependiendo si voy a programar una cosa u otra y cada perfil pues tendrá sus propios plugins instalados, por ejemplos

Perfil 1: Tiene un plugin de snippet para Angular
Perfil 2: Tiene un plugin de snippet para React

Mientras el perfil 1 este activo los plugin del perfil 2 no funcionan y mientras el perfil 2 este activo los plugin del perfil 1 no funcionan.

espero haberme explicado bien, es un poco lioso.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

Con Settings sync puedes generar y guardar tu perfil por usuario

[settings exentension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Shan.code-settings-sync)

y con solo un comando de sincronizacion actualulizas tu perfil de usuario,
se genera un token por cada perfil y

Escribes ">Sync"

La otra manera es que guardes el archivo settingns.js para la configuracion de visual studio por cada perfil y lo actualices para cuando cambies de perfil, por eso veo que la primer opcion es mejor.

saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Create a directory por specific extensions, for example in my mac:

mkdir -p code_profiles/java/{exts,data}

then use parameters: extensions-dir y user-data-dir to invoke Visual Studio Code:

code --extensions-dir ~/code_profiles/java/exts --user-data-dir ~/code_profiles/java/data

you could use one set of directories for each language o framework.

Comment: Bienvenido, revisa [answer]. Recuerda que el idioma oficial del sitio es el español.